# Anvil - Cheat the repair counter

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had a very nice pickaxe with great enchantments on it. I noticed at one point, that I can't repair it anymore ("too expensive!"). I found [information about this on the Minecraft-Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil_mechanics#Prior_Work_penalty).

Is there any way to surpass this counter? It really annoys me, I worked hours to get a pickaxe with Silk Touch and now everything starts from scratch. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because of how powerful the tool is, and because it contains a vast amount of enchantments. You get the "too expensive!" note if you don't have enough exp, but you're trying to repair it with another diamond pickaxe, not raw diamonds. Try using raw diamonds and you should be able to repair it with a sufficient amount of exp.

Keep in mind that this is the vanilla method of getting around of it, and it is greatly expensive. It might be such a burden that it would be worth trying to enchant a new pickaxe from 30 levels.

---

> The level cost on an anvil is capped at 40. Any combination or repair that costs more than 40 levels will never be possible in survival mode, no matter how many levels you actually have. There is no cap in creative mode.
>
> Each time you repair or combine an item, the level cost increases by 2. You can mitigate this, somewhat, by renaming the item first. This will add some to the level cost for future repairs/combinations, but it makes the item exempt from the increasing cost each time you do.

-- [Source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/discussion/172184-anvil-says-too-expensive).

**This is no longer valid as of 1.8.**

---

The easier method is if you're hosting a server, and you installed the Bukkit plugin you can do the command `/repair` in chat and it will automatically repair that piece to full durability.

You can also get the plugin [Better Anvils](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1286937-better-anvils-removes-the-level-limit) for a server to migate the exp cap.

Comment: Renaming no longer locks the repair cost at a specific level in 1.8+. Thus renaming is only for aesthetic purposes now.

Comment: Hello Chantola, before I accept I have another quick question: A level cap doesn't matter, if you don't try to make a full repair at once, right? Levels don't bother me, since I have an EXP farm. I just want to repair my enchanted gear forever, the costs don't matter. Is this possible?

Comment: @TrudleR Without mods or plugins, it doesn't seem possible any more. It used to work because you could reset the cost by renaming the item, but since that doesn't work you eventually will not be able to repair the item because of the growth of the item exp cost, and you cannot repair items that cost more than 40 levels. It shouldn't be really a problem though, so no need to stress over it.

Comment: This is still just theoretical, because if you never let the pickaxe reach a low durability, you may be able to sustain a very, very long period of time if you constantly repair it with diamonds. And exp. LOTS of it.